# How to track file lifetime using lsof?

Tags: linux, socket, lsof

I have read article https://tailscale.com/blog/case-of-spiky-file-descriptors/ where author investigates anomalies with the amount of open file descriptors.
He said that made snapshot of open files using `lsof` which allowed him to track lifetime of file:

```
01:12:17.24    tailcontr 142810 ubuntu  273u     IPv6   5725049    0t0     TCP 172.31.10.244:https->1.2.3.4:57666 (ESTABLISHED)
01:13:32.17    tailcontr 142810 ubuntu  273u     IPv6   5725049    0t0     TCP 172.31.10.244:https->1.2.3.4:57666 (CLOSE_WAIT)
01:14:03.22    tailcontr 142810 ubuntu  273u     sock       0,8    0t0 5725049 protocol: TCPv6
01:16:53.93    (socket is removed)
```

What flags should be used to track lifetime of file as given in the example above?

P.S: I want to investigate similar problem with TCPv6 connections. According to `lsof -u <user>` I have a lot of files looking like:

```
01:14:03.22    tailcontr 142810 ubuntu  273u     sock       0,8    0t0 5725049 protocol: TCPv6
```

And I want to understand where were these connections made to.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `lsof` will be not the exact tool. Better activate `auditd` and configure it to track creation and deletion of files.
In `/etc/audit.rules` you can add something like

```
-w /path/to/file -p war -k fileops
-a always,exit -F dir=/path/to/ -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rename -S renameat  -k fileops
```

This will monitor read,write,append file operations. And delete (unlink) operations in the directory where the file is created.

The records later can be filtered by keyname `fileops`